# cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::string& to an rvalue of type ‘std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I have below code. In order to cut off cost of calling fun. I set `fun(string &a)` use reference parameter. But it can't be compiled.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void
fun (string &a) {
        string concat = "prefix_" + a;
        cout << "[fun] concat:" << concat << endl;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
        fun("test");
        return 0;
}
```

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::string&’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string&’} to an rvalue of type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’}

I change `fun (string &a)` to `fun (string a)`. It works.
But it seems to lead to unnecessary construction.

BTW, How shold I write the right code to minimum cost of unnecessary implicit construction?

Comment: Pass the parameter by `const&` not just by `&`.

Comment: The gist of it is that `"test"` is not a `std::string`. You can't avoid constructing at least one object here.